# How to process multiple mics input Audio stream in matlab in real time

Tags: matlab, audio, signals

I need to get 3 input audio stream to matlab simultaneously using 3 USB mics and find out the highest amplitude in real time.

this is the mics initialization

```
mic1= dsp.AudioRecorder('DeviceName','ÇáãíßÑæÝæä (10- USB PnP Sound Device)', 'SampleRate', 48000, 'NumChannels', 1);
mic2= dsp.AudioRecorder('DeviceName','ÇáãíßÑæÝæä (9- USB PnP Sound Device)', 'SampleRate', 48000, 'NumChannels', 1);
mic3= dsp.AudioRecorder('DeviceName','ÇáãíßÑæÝæä (8- USB PnP Sound Device)', 'SampleRate', 48000, 'NumChannels', 1);



frame1=step(mic1);
frame2=step(mic2);
frame3=step(mic3);
```

---

what are the next steps?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding this statement: `find out the highest amplitude in real time`.  Do you want to look at each audio signal individually, and find their highest amplitudes overall?  Please explain.

Comment: I want to compare the three Audio signals as they feed into the system and find out the highest one (the loudest sound) at certain time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By examining your code, you have three audio signals with one channel each.  If I understand what you want correctly, you want to find the highest sound made by any one signal overall over time.  However, if I understand you correctly, you can't do this in real time as `step` for the `AudioWriter` can only capture one frame at a time.  Because you're specifically trying to capture from all three audio devices, and the only way for you to capture audio is with `step`, you'll have to serially call `step` for each signal that you have.

Therefore, you'll need to capture all three audio signals separately, and then do your analysis.  You'll also want to clip the sound after a certain point, so perhaps something like 5 seconds.  Therefore, you'd do something like:

```
time_end = 5;

%// Capture audio signal 1
tic;    
frame1 = [];
while toc < time_end
  audio_in = step(mic1);
  frame1 = [frame1; audio_in(:)];
end

%// Capture audio signal 2
tic;    
frame2 = [];
while toc < time_end
  audio_in = step(mic2);
  frame2 = [frame2; audio_in(:)];
end


%// Capture audio signal 3
tic;    
frame3 = [];
while toc < time_end
  audio_in = step(mic3);
  frame3 = [frame3; audio_in(:)];
end
```

---

After this point, because the sounds will probably all be uneven length, you'll want to zero pad all of them so they all match the same length.  After this, it's a matter of first finding the maximum amplitude for each sample for all three signals, and then finding the maximum out of all of this.

I'm not quite sure how the signals are shaped... if they are row or column vectors, so let's just make sure they're all column vectors.  Then, use [`max`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html) and operate along the columns and find the maximum for each point in time, then find the maximum out of all of these.

Therefore:

```
%// Find lengths for all three signals
l1 = numel(frame1);
l2 = numel(frame2);
l3 = numel(frame3);
max_length = max([l1, l2, l3]);

%// Zero pad signals to make same length
frame1_pad = zeros(max_length,1);
frame2_pad = zeros(max_length,1);
frame2_pad = zeros(max_length,1);
frame1_pad(1:l1) = frame1;
frame2_pad(1:l2) = frame2;
frame3_pad(1:l3) = frame3;

%// Find maximum among each sample
max_signal = max([frame1_pad, frame2_pad, frame3_pad], [], 1);

%// Find the maximum amplitude overall and location
[max_amplitude, loc] = max(max_signal);
```

---

`max_amplitude` will contain the highest point overall at a particular time point for each of the three signals, and `loc` will tell you the location in the array of where it was found.  If you want to find the actual time it occured, simply take `loc` and multiply by your sampling **time** `(1/48000)`.  Bear in mind that `loc` will be 1-indexed instead of 0-indexed, and so you need to subtract by 1 before multiplying by the sampling rate.

Therefore:

```
time_it_happened = (loc-1)*(1/48000);
```

`time_it_happened` will contain that time which the highest amplitude happened.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much.I want to vote up for your answer but I have no enough reputations.